# Origen de "bocajarro". ¿Cómo adquirió la locución adverbial "a bocajarro" sus significados actuales?

Tags: etimología, locuciones, compuestos

De la propia entrada del DRAE para "[bocajarro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5iZt2g6)" aprendemos que la locución adverbial "a bocajarro" tiene dos significados: "desde muy cerca" y "de improviso":

> 1. loc. adv. A quemarropa, **desde muy cerca**. *Le disparó a bocajarro.* U. t. c. loc. adj. *Un tiro a bocajarro.*
> 2. loc. adv. **De improviso**, inopinadamente, sin preparación ninguna. *Soltó a bocajarro toda la verdad.* U. t. c. loc. adj. *Una pregunta a bocajarro.*

No es que ambos significados estén muy relacionados en principio, pero lo que me llama la atención es primero la simpleza de la locución adverbial (simplemente una preposición junto a la propia palabra "bocajarro", que no tiene significado fuera de la locución adverbial) y segundo que la propia palabra parece ser una palabra compuesta ([boca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5i6aRwS) + [jarro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MNfGAg0)), que a primera vista poco tendría que ver con los significados de las locuciones adverbiales.

Me parece curioso tener una locución adverbial que es prácticamente solo una palabra que no tiene significado alguno fuera de la propia locución (la propia palabra es casi la locución adverbial) y cuyo significado parece estar poco o nada relacionado con la manera en que parece estar formada esta palabra compuesta.

¿Cuál es el origen y evolución de la palabra "bocajarro" para derivar en los significados actuales de la locución "a bocajarro"?

**Nota**: Existe también la locución "a boca de jarro" (puede verse en la entrada del DRAE para "[boca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5i6aRwS)"), que se usa "para denotar la acción de beber sin tasa" y que parecer ser sinónima de "a bocajarro", sin que sea evidente tampoco la relación entre "beber sin tasa", "desde muy cerca" y "de improviso".

Comment: [Signo de boca de mina de Hoffmann](https://www.cun.es/diccionario-medico/terminos/signo-boca-mina-hoffmann)

Answer (score 1):

No consigo encontrar documentos suficientes como para dar una respuesta en condiciones como me gustaría, así que vamos con una respuesta tentativa con lo que he podido encontrar.

Resulta que antes de la expresión *a boca de jarro* existía *a boca de costal*, con el mismo significado de "sin mesura, sin tasa" pero sin restringir el significado a líquidos. Lo puedes ver en frases como esta:

> *[...] entrando en la feria y sabiendo que ay la mercaduría que él busca, luego da señal porque a otro no se venda hasta que sobre mesa desata el talegón del dinero que trae copioso, donde a boca de costal paga y desenbolsa hasta no quedar nada y sacudir si algo queda.*
>
> Francisco de Osuna, "Primera parte del Abecedario espiritual", 1528 (España).

Esta expresión está registrada tanto en el *Covarrubias* (1611) como en el *Autoridades* (1726). Sin embargo, ninguno de estos diccionarios recoge la expresión *a boca de jarro*, que se usaba con el mismo propósito de "sin mesura" pero referido a líquidos ("beber sin mesura"). Esta llegó con la edición del diccionario de 1770. Pero de momento no hay rastro de la acepción que nos ocupa, que llegó a su vez en 1817:

> Á BOCA DE CAÑON. m. adv. Muy de cerca, como: le tiró á BOCA DE CAÑON.
>   Á BOCA DE JARRO. m. adv. Lo mismo que Á BOCA DE CAÑON.

La expresión *a boca de cañón* se usaba de forma muy similar a la de *a boca de jarro*:

> *Fue gran prodigio el que pudiesse el general don Martín de Vrsúa conseguir el que no disparassen el tiro de cruxía ni los pedreros sus soldados, porque si lo huvieran hecho, como querían, huviera sido horrible la mortandad y destrozo que huvieran hecho en los infieles, assí por ser tan grandíssimo número y estar tan espesos, como por cogerlos casi a boca de cañón.*
>
> Juan de Villagutierre Sotomayor, "Historia de la conquista de la provincia del Itzá", 1701 (España).

Sin embago, fue la expresión *boca de jarro* la que se empezó a usar más. Este es el caso más antiguo que encuentro:

> *Esta hubiera callado hasta verificarse el desembarco; pero, ¿qué recurso quedaba a los que le hubiesen hecho cuando, descubriéndola, hubiese roto sobre ellos su fuego a metralla, casi a boca de jarro?*
>
> Conde de Fernán Núñez (Carlos Gutiérrez de los Ríos), "Vida de Carlos III", c 1790 (España).

Ahora bien, ¿por qué mudó el sentido de esta expresión desde el original "beber sin mesura"? Tengo dos alternativas:

1. Que se asemejara el hecho de salir la metralla desde la boca del arma con la misma copiosidad que cuando bebes a boca de jarro. Pero no tiene mucho sentido porque entonces eso habría valido para cualquier disparo en general.
2. Que las heridas provocadas por dichos disparos hicieran sangran al desafortunado con la misma copiosidad que cuando bebes a boca de jarro. Esta me parece la opción más plausible, pero no he encontrado nada que la respalde.

La expresión *a boca de jarro* acabó contrayéndose, como sabemos, en la expresión *a bocajarro* por pérdida de la preposición intermedia. El primer caso así lo encuentro en la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> *Sin duda habia recibido el tiro á bocajarro, porque parte de sus cabellos negros estaba quemada: en la mano izquierda tenia una pistóla que evidentemente acababa de ser disparada.*
>
> La Ilustración (Madrid). 13/10/1856, página 7.

Sin embargo, no fue hasta 1970 cuando la palabra *bocajarro* entró en el DLE, incluyendo ya su significado como "de improviso", que imagino que derivaría del hecho de que los disparos a bocajarro se efectuaran de dicha manera.

Comment: @walen he estado leyendo con las atención los textos que usan "a boca de cañón" y en realidad sí que parecen todos usarse con el sentido de "estar muy cerca de un arma de fuego". He cambiado pues la redacción de ese párrafo.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me parece muy evidente la relación entre "beber sin tasa" (sic) y "desde muy cerca".

Para poder beber un líquido en un jarro sin una taza, prácticamente hay que pegarse a la boca del mismo para no errar y así derramar el mínimo del líquido; es decir, "desde muy cerca". De otra manera, existe una alta probabilidad de que terminemos empapados con el líquido.

Así mismo, un disparo a boca de jarro (a bocajarro) disminuye las probabilidades de errar el blanco.

El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas no da un origen ni una evolución de la expresión, así que mis comentarios son a título personal.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Me llama la atención ese "SIC" que has puesto la lado de "beber sin tasa". Esa es la definición literal dada por el DRAE (comprueba el enlace). No intenta decir "beber sin **taza**" o algo similar. No hay errata. De todas formas, se puede argumentar que poner la boca en el jarro ("beber a morro"  - poner la boca de uno en la boca del jarro) puede interpretarse como "de forma precipitada, ansiosa, etc." pero no tanto de "improvisada, inesperada, sin preparar". Tampoco "desde muy cerca", porque así es como bebes todo (con la boca en el continente). Habría que respaldar la conjetura con algo más.

Comment: Mea culpa. Dejo el texto sin editar como referencia a los demás lectores.
Entonces, según el DRAE, "beber sin tasa" se refiere a "beber sin restricción". La relación ahora no me parece tan evidente como al principio; estoy como tú.